# Could not write pid to lock file

Tags: raspbian, startx

I was working on my Pi when suddenly it stuck. I attempted to restart but upon entering `startx` I got the error "`Could not write pid to lock file in /tmp/xtX0-lock`'

I've looked around and many people advised running the df -h Command. I have done that and nothing has changed for me.

Looking at the error screen it seems to be out of space, but placing it on my windows computer it shows me space. But even if it really is out of space. How do I clear up some items or what can I delete as I really have scripts I need. 
Thank you

[image: Error SCreen]

Comment: Windows does not show that full partion (which is mounted as root), windows shows you only the fat-partition (mounted as /boot) - which is not full. You'll need to get rid of some files, your package managers cache is a good point to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by a stale lock file from a crashed previous session.  As root, look for an existing `/tmp/xtX0-lock` and delete it, then try starting X again.

Being out of drive space will also do it.  Try deleting everything under `/var/log`, then use `sudo apt-get erase <packages...>` to perhaps remove some packages you don't actually need.

NOTE: **Don't** delete the directory structure under `/var/log`...just delete files; otherwise some services that expect certain log directories to exist will fail to start.

Realistically, 4GB is much too small a root device on a system which runs X.  Image the SD card onto a larger one and expand the fs.

Comment: Could be, but nonetheless the root partition shows 100% usage, which is not a good thing.

Comment: @Ghanima Agreed.  As noted in my edit (which I was typing as you commented) I answered before I had fully read the question...

Comment: sudo apt-get erase?

Comment: @Grace see edits... yes use `sudo` (we old-school linux users still talk about doing things "as root" which is equivalent to putting `sudo` in front of whatever)

Comment: Meh...I deleted the /var/log folder...it wouldnt start, had to reformat my SD card. Lost everytthing :( but thanks

Comment: Sorry to hear that :-(  Since you're already going down that path, let me suggest: Get a bigger SD card!  4GB is way too small.

Comment: @Lotharyx I actually don't understand the file system. it's actually an 8GB SD card. if the OS takes 4gigs, shouldnt I have at least 3gb for myself?

Comment: @Grace not if it isn't partitioned appropriately.  The card itself is just a big chunk of space; for the OS to understand how to use it, it must be divided up into partitions that can be mounted.  If this is a fresh Raspbian installation, use `sudo raspi-config` and select `Expand Filesystem` to have the root partition automatically expanded to access the whole card.

Comment: @Grace It sounds like you could benefit from learning more about how "block storage devices" (hard drives, SD cards, etc) work on Linux.  Go googling about "partition tables" and "file systems" and "mount points" under Linux.  Snapshot: Partition table tells the OS about sections of the device and how big they are.  File system organizes the space inside a partition.  Mount point is how the OS accesses the file system.

Comment: @Grace in your case, you have a partition on a device that is smaller than the physical space on the device (which is always the case when writing an image that's smaller than the whole device).  raspi-config will increase the size of that partition to cover the whole physical space, then resize the filesystem to organize the larger space, and then violà, more room!

Comment: PS if you found any of my comments or answer helpful, please consider upvoting them :-)

Comment: @Lotharyx I formatted the card yesterday not BRAND new, installed a few apps and some scripts. Can I safely run this command?

Comment: @Grace - yes.  Expanding a partition into previously-unpartitioned space beyond it (which is the situation here) is always safe because it is only grabbing more unused space; the used space is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation after installing opencv from source files. even erasing of files was only hardly possible - sometimes with crazy error msgs.

i uninstalled the gimp package.
i deleted the source files of opencv.
after deleting the whole opencv the strange effects were gone.